# How to save an Access database using VBA program?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In order to save a record in my MSAccess database via a VBA application, I wrote the following. But when running the code it discards acCmdSaveRecord as an undefined variable. Can anyone give some leads about this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SavingAccessDB()

     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VBA Window, select Tools menu,  then  References...

Tick the checkbox:
Microsoft Access xxx Object Library

Comment: Thanks. It recognizes the function now. But says that the "SaveRecord" command is not available for the moment (error 2046). I suspect it has to do with the version of my .mdb ?

Comment: The command you using has a context and that context is the current form with the current focus. You don't mention where/where/how your code is being run and that is VERY important. Such code only works if you have a form open with a record ready to be saved.